# How can i select a file in Delphi

Tags: delphi, vcl

I need to make 'Graphic User Interface' and I need some VCL component to select some file.

This component have to select the file, but the user don't have to put the name of the file.

I am searching information but nothing helps me.

Comment: Huh? Google [delphi select file](https://www.google.nl/search?q=delphi+select+file) or [delphi open file](https://www.google.nl/search?q=delphi+open+file) and you have your answers. Not that you can't ask here, but it's faster if you search.

Comment: Bravo for the question, Google got me here! -1 for evil Jan Doggen

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog) can be used for this purpose.

See also [UsingDialogs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/UsingDialogs_(Delphi)).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  selectedFile: string;
  dlg: TOpenDialog;
begin
  selectedFile := '';
  dlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    dlg.InitialDir := 'C:\';
    dlg.Filter := 'All files (*.*)|*.*';
    if dlg.Execute(Handle) then
      selectedFile := dlg.FileName;
  finally
    dlg.Free;
  end;

  if selectedFile <> '' then
    <your code here to handle the selected file>
end;
```

Notice that the example here assumes that a `TButton` named `Button1` is dropped to the form and the  `TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject)` procedure is assigned to the button `OnClick` event.

---

Multiple file extensions can be used in the `TOpenDialog.Filter` property by concatenating them together using the `|` (pipe) character like this:

```
'AutoCAD drawing|*.dwg|Drawing Exchange Format|*.dxf'
```

Answer (score -1):

I FIND my problem. 
My problem was that i was not making any button to open the Dialog.
I make a TEdit. This Tedit have a procedure (Onlclik) like that:

```
procedure TForm1.SelectFile(Sender: TObject);
begin

  openDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(self);
  openDialog.InitialDir := 'C:\';
  openDialog.Options := [ofFileMustExist];

  // Allow only .dpr and .pas files to be selected
  openDialog.Filter :=
    'All files (*.*)|*.*';
  // Display the open file dialog
  if openDialog.Execute
  then ShowMessage('File : '+openDialog.FileName)
  else ShowMessage('Open file was cancelled');

  // Free up the dialog
  openDialog.Free;

end;
```

Comment: please use a try/finally clause when dealing with objects, as shown in the excellent answer from @fantaghirocco